# Foundry's Anvil localnode not prcessing transactions?

Tags: ethers.js, json-rpc, foundry

I've deployed smart contracts using the ContractFactory Objects provided by ethers.js 5.7 and they were working quite fine but today the contracts don't seem to be getting deployed; in fact any transaction of any kind is not being processed.

But the factory still outputs an address for the deployed contracts and when i query them using 'cast' it returns the following error:

```bash
➜  ~ cast call 0xEaA95FF42CE9b59D539805b7220a63E426566830 "getPrice()(uint256)"
Error: 
contract 0xeaa95ff42ce9b59d539805b7220a63e426566830 does not have any code
```

Here's the code:

```js
const metamask = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
        window.ethereum,
        "any"
      );
      const account = await metamask.getSigner();
      console.log(account);
      const factory = new ContractFactory(
        orderManagerAbi,
        orderManagerByteCode,
        account
      );
      const tPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, 18);
      console.log("deploying...");
      const contract = await factory.deploy(buyerAddress, sellerAddr, tPrice);
      console.log(contract.address);
```